# Revoke access of microsoft/outlook account using outlook or graph rest API

Tags: php, rest, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API for integration of microsoft/outlook calendar in my app.

[API reference is here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/calendar)

I want to revoke user's access of their calendars from my app but didn't find any way to do so. I tried with following api but no luck:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that command would delete the `user` entirely. So while that would certainly remove them from the calendar, I'm guessing this isn't the outcome you're looking for. :-)

If you're looking to remove the permission for your app, there are a couple of ways to trigger this:

1. Simply stop requesting that user's calendars from your app. This won't revoke permission to the calendar however so this likely isn't sufficient.
2. Drop `Calendars.Read` and `Calendars.ReadWrie` from your list of requested scopes.

   - In order to ensure this change is reflected in the user's account, you'll need to re-authenticate the user with the query param `prompt=consent` auth URI.
3. Have the user revoke permission for your application entirely. This is done by visiting https://myapps.microsoft.com.

   - There are certain apps that a user cannot directly revoke. These are apps who were granted access at the organization level. To revoke these, an Administrator will need to do this in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

Comment: @mlafleur I can't remove scopes from my list as these are used globally in the app. If the above api would delete the user entirely, then does this delete the user account ? I think It should only revoke the user's acsess.

Comment: If you tell Graph API to delete a user, it will **delete the user object from the Active Directory**.  This is the purpose of calling Create, Read, Update and Delete functions against a User object in AD.